# Using ref without useRef in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I was reading through the React docs and I came across [how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node)

Now over here the example provided is as follows

```
function MeasureExample() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  const measuredRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1 ref={measuredRef}>Hello, world</h1>
      <h2>The above header is {Math.round(height)}px tall</h2>
    </>
  );
}
```

**My Question is**

How are we getting the `ref` value without using the `useRef` hook aren't we suppose to use the `useRef` hook when we want the instance of a DOM node ?

So what I mean by getting the `ref` value by `useRef` is as follows:

`const measuredRef = useRef()`
then using it as  `<h1 ref={measuredRef}>Hello, world</h1>`

If the `ref` provided in the example code is a reference to a function then shouldn't it be named as `handleMeasureRef` ?

Also there is statement below the code

> We didn’t choose useRef in this example because an object ref doesn’t
> notify us about changes to the current ref value.

Why it doesn't notify about the changes is it because it doesn't causes a re-render ?

Does that mean using only `ref` without `useRef` notifies about changes ?